# How to cast mshtml.IHTMLDivElement to mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass?

Tags: c#, .net, mshtml

How to cast  **mshtml.IHTMLDivElement**  to  **mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass**?

```
IHTMLElementCollection collection = doc.body.all;

foreach (var htmlElem in collection)
{
    if (htmlElem is mshtml.IHTMLDivElement)
    {
         mshtml.IHTMLDivElement div = htmlElem as mshtml.IHTMLDivElement;
         if (div != null)
         {
            //  HTMLDivElementClass divClass = (HTMLDivElementClass)div;  ?????????                      
         }
     }            
}
```

I need to access HTMLDivElementClass  to be able to get all members of it.

[image]

Comment: Why do you need to do the cast? What's wrong with your commented out code?

Comment: @vcsjones  Because I cannot access all properties I need inside HTMLDivElementClass.    IHTMLDivElement  has only 2 properites...   For example I need to get ID of the DIV and etc...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code almost correct. Not sure what you want.

Please change your code like below

```
 mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection collection = (mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection)objDocument.body.all;

            foreach (var htmlElem in collection)
            {
                if (htmlElem is mshtml.IHTMLDivElement)
                {
                    mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass div = htmlElem as mshtml.HTMLDivElementClass;
                    if (div != null)
                    {
                    //DO YOUR CODE HERE 
                     //div.IHTMLElement_id
                    }
                }
            }
```

It is working for me and in "div" object is of the type "HTMLDivElementClass"

And one more suggestion if you want to all the DIV tag only from the page then use the following line of code.

```
mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection collection = (mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection)objDocument.getElementsByName("div");
```

Instead of

```
 mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection collection = (mshtml.IHTMLElementCollection)objDocument.body.all;
```

That will remove your condition to check element is DIV or not.

Hope this help to you.